what's the state of the art for installing nodejs these days?
it's june 2024
what's the state of the art for installing nodejs on Ubuntu these days ?
snap has a 20.x version but it says

error: This revision of snap "node" was published using classic
confinement and thus may perform
arbitrary system changes outside of the security sandbox that snaps are usually confined to,
which may put your system at risk.
   If you understand and want to proceed repeat the command including --classic.


Should I be scared of this advisory ?
the apt collection has a much older version
many videos on youtube suggest using the installer from the github repo
I'm confused

The APT packages are not confined at all. Therefore, if you installed nodejs in any previous version of Ubuntu, it was not confined. Since node needs to connect to a lot of other components, its snap version is deliberately not confined.
